# user generated 50% width images side by side with padding

Tags: html, css

I'm using the Kirby CMS to build a site, and I need to be able to have the user put an image on a page that is 50% of the container and floated left (so a second 50% image would be beside it).

I almost got it working - the images are side by side, but if I add any margins, the second image will of course go to a new line. Because I used `box-sizing: border-box` I can use padding to create some space between them, while keeping them on one line, but the images have borders and shadows that get extended with the padding.

Because this content is user generated through an admin panel, I cannot explicitly wrap each image in its own div (where I could normally apply the padding to). Is there another route I could go with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code? And maybe a negative margin helps?

Comment: Negative margins did the trick, thanks! I went with this in the end:

`img.half:nth-child(even) {margin-right: -20px;}`

Answer (score 1):

As **Flauwekeul** mentioned, a negative margin did the trick.

```
img.half {
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
img.half:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```